# Pymongo update_one

Tags: python-3.x, pymongo-3.x

I have JSON like below

```
{"city": "New York"}, {"$set": {"city": "Toronto"}}
```

When I directly give this in the update_one method

```
database.collection.update_one({"city": "New York"}, {"$set": {"city": "Toronto"}})
```

it worked great no issues.

But when I assigned to a variable like

```
temp = {"city": "New York"}, {"$set": {"city": "Toronto"}}
database.collection.update_one(temp)
```

Which is giving me the below error:

```
TypeError("update_one() missing 1 required positional argument: 'update'",)
```

I have used

`json.loads(temp)`

as well as

`json.dumps(temp)`

did not work for me? Any Idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you do:

```
database.collection.update_one({"city": "New York"}, {"$set": {"city": "Toronto"}})
```

you are correctly passing two positional arguments: the first one (corresponding to `filter`) is `{"city": "New York"}`, and the second one (corresponding to `update`) is `{"$set": {"city": "Toronto"}}`.

However when you do:

```
temp = {"city": "New York"}, {"$set": {"city": "Toronto"}}
database.collection.update_one(temp)
```

You are now passing a **single** positional argument, which is a tuple, hence the error message about the missing argument.

What you need to do is either:

a) Expand the tuple as positional arguments:

```
temp = {"city": "New York"}, {"$set": {"city": "Toronto"}}
database.collection.update_one(*temp)  # Notice the "*" here
```

b) Pass multiple positional arguments:

```
filter, update = {"city": "New York"}, {"$set": {"city": "Toronto"}}  # Tuple expanded here, as two variable
database.collection.update_one(filter, update)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, Changed my code and working as expected. Thanks again.